# block theme FSE - save changes to the theme?

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing

I'm using WordPress 6.1 and trying out FSE.
When editing block theme in FSE - is it possible to just save changes to the same theme without having to export the theme first?

Comment: if this is a theme you got from somewhere else then those changes would be destroyed when the theme has an update, so it's better to export the theme and then install and activate it. You can always re-export and reupload it with the new name you choose to update the files

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you. Yeah, that is my understanding. now Im seeing that they are working on some updates to the Gutenberg that would allow theme to be saved onto the filesystem - but I guess its not released yet, check it out: https://youtu.be/8Vj_Oh6jMHw?t=281.

Comment: @TomJNowell ahh nvm - looks like that theme saving functionality might have been some test: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/40385 that has since been abandoned. Looks like I'll have to export the theme then.

Comment: @TomJNowell on additional view - this plugin seems to let me do just that  - save changes back to the theme and more: https://github.com/WordPress/create-block-theme. noice

Comment: nice find, you could write that up as an answer? Then we can upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of digging into the subject and looks like they were working on some updates to Gutenberg that would allow them to be saved onto the filesystem: youtu.be/8Vj_Oh6jMHw?t=281.

But those efforts were later abandoned: github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/40385, as adding that support into WordPress core was complicated.

I then found this plugin that lets one do just that - save changes back to the theme and more: github.com/WordPress/create-block-theme.